# Must a CFII be instrument current to provide instrument training?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency, instrument-rating

Can a CFII conduct training for an instrument student in VFR conditions if the CFII isn’t instrument current?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to make it a little clearer but if I got something wrong then don't hesitate to edit again or just roll back my changes. I assumed you're asking about the US; whenever you ask about rules or regulations please always tell us which country or regulations you mean. The [tour] may be helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: That... is a really good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements for providing instrument instruction are in [14 CFR 61.195(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1195) and they don't mention currency at all. There are also various FAA legal interpretations on whether or not CFIs (not CFIIs) require an instrument rating to provide instrument training (see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54600/62)), and what instrument training requires a CFII in the first place (see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59375/62)) and none of them mention currency either.

So no, there is no requirement for a CFII to be instrument current when providing instrument training.

Having said that, [61.65(d)(2)(ii)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_165) requires instrument students to do a cross-country under IFR with an instructor. An instructor who isn't instrument current couldn't provide that specific training flight, although obviously the student could use a different instructor. And many CFIIs like to take their instrument students into IMC to let them experience how different it is from being under the hood.

All in all, it's in a CFII's best interests to remain instrument current but it isn't required.

Comment: I think it’s best to be current before taking on an instrument student so the CFII is sharp and giving the best possible instruction

Comment: @DanielRackley I don’t agree. Everything else being equal, a CFII who is actively training students would be a much better choice as an instructor than someone who is current but hasn’t trained anyone in a while.